# Using WM_Close in c#

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to close the window, by searching the window name in taskbar.
But i one case, my window will not appear in the taskbar. In that case, `WM_Close` could not close the window. Whats the other way to do it using `WM_Close` ???

```
    void DaemonTerminamtionHook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        DaemonResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure, you want to Terminate Daemon?", "Terminate Daemon", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        if (DaemonResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            //Free the resources of ShellBasics and terminate Daemon here.
            IntPtr hWnd = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "DAEMON TAB BAR");
            bool ret = CloseWindow(hWnd);
        }
    }

    //WM_Close
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;

    static bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero); 
        return true;
    }
```

---

Now using the below code...But getting error in

"IntPtr hWnd = PostMessage(IntPtr.Zero, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);"

where to provide the window name in order to close that ???

---

```
 void DaemonTerminamtionHook_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        DaemonResult = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure, you want to Terminate Daemon?", "Terminate Daemon", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        if (DaemonResult == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            IntPtr hWnd = PostMessage(IntPtr.Zero, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            bool ret = CloseWindow(hWnd);
        }
    }



    static uint WM_CLOSE = 0x10;
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    static bool CloseWindow(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        bool returnValue = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_CLOSE, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (!returnValue)
            throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Sorry misread your question.

Use [FindWindow/FindWindowEx](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindowEx.html) instead.

Comment: @Preet, Thanks for your support. Can u tell me how to pass the parameter for :

 void PostMessageSafe( HandleRef hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam )

Comment: @Preet, where to pass the window name here ?

Comment: @Preet, please refer to the updated code on top, it is giving some errors as the paramerters does not match and please tell me where to provide the windows name inorder to close it.

Comment: I suggest reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499(VS.85).aspx to set up your window with a classname so findwindow can find it. Or use SPY++ to find this value in dev