# How to "End Task" not "Kill" or "Terminate"?

Tags: c#, windows, vbscript, task

I have a 3G card to provide internet to a remote computer... I have to run a program(provided with the card) to establish the connection... since connections suddenly is lost I wrote a script that Kills the program and reopens it so that the connection is reestablished, there are certain versions of this program that don't kill the connection when killed/terminated, just when closed properly.

so I am looking for a script or program that "Properly Closes" a window so I can close it and reopen it in case the connection is lost.

this is the code that kills the program

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strProcessKill 
strComputer = "."
strProcessKill = "'Telcel3G.exe'" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill )
For Each objProcess in colProcess
objProcess.Terminate()
Next 
WSCript.Echo "Just killed process " & strProcessKill _
& " on " & strComputer
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: You need to post some code so we can see what you mean (the code opening the connection and the code that kills/terminates).

Comment: `Taskkill /im imagename.exe` asks an app to close. `Taskkill /f /im imagename.exe` forces an app to close. You are using 16 lines to do what one line in a batch can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use VBScript, one easy way would be to activate the app and then use SendKeys to restore it if it's minimized and send it "alt-f4". It's hacky, but it may be easier than finding the main window's handle, and it might work well enough for you.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objWMIService, objProcess, colProcess
Dim strComputer, strProcessKill 
strComputer = "."
strProcessKill = "'Telcel3G.exe'" 

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _ 
& strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

dim WshShell
set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_Process Where Name = " & strProcessKill )
For Each objProcess in colProcess
WshShell.AppActivate objProcess.ProcessId
WScript.Sleep 1000 
WshShell.Sendkeys "% r"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.Sendkeys "%{F4}"
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the basic idea is to shut the process down cleanly, as opposed to abruptly terminating it.  One way would be to post a Windows message to the main window with WM_CLOSE.

(You might be able to simulate this by sending keystrokes corresponding to Alt+F4, but it's best to just send WM_CLOSE.)

Comment: You don't want to focus the window.  You want to find its HWND based on its title and then send a message.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391661/using-wm-close-in-c

Comment: I think what Alt-F4 does is to send a `WM_QUIT`. No need to emulate keystrokes.

Comment: I would appreciate it if the downvoter would explain their reasoning.